# How to make a button stay above the footer when scrolling towards the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a 'feedback' button. The should consistently be shown on the lower left side of the screen. [image: The Feedback button]

Except when you are about to reach the footer, it should stay on top,

[image]

and not continue to slide down when you continue to view the footer.

[image]

Here is my HTML markup:

```
    <div class="TMDOQ-tab navbar-fixed-bottom">
  <a href="#" id="TMDOQ_button">
          <img src= "assets/TMDOQ.png" alt= "Logo-DitoMismo" class="hidden-phone" id="logoTMDOQ">
        </a>
  <div class="TMDOQ-form">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label">First name:</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Type something…">
        </div>          
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label">Email Address:</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Type something…">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label">Cellphone Number:</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Type something…">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label">Item Name:</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Type something…">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
      <button type="submit" class="btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS code :

```
 .TMDOQ-tab
{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;

}
.TMDOQ-tab a 
{
    display:block;
    height:20px;
    width:100px;
    text-align:center;
    background: url('../img/header-footer.png');


    padding:8px;
    float:left;
    cursor:pointer;
    /*Font*/
    color:#FFF;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:18px;


    -webkit-border-radius: 0 20px 0 0;
            border-radius: 0 20px 0 0;
    background-clip: padding-box;


}
.TMDOQ-tab .TMDOQ-form
{
    clear:both;
    height:auto;
    width:auto;

    background: url('../img/header-footer.png');
    padding:30px;
    display: none;

    -webkit-border-radius: 0 20px 0 0;
            border-radius: 0 20px 0 0;
    background-clip: padding-box;

}
```

While the JS I am Using:

```
$("#TMDOQ_button").click(function()
{
        $('.TMDOQ-form').slideToggle();
});
```

This what I think is the closest thing of what I am trying to do, although they are using jQuery to which I don't know how to implement on my code, but instead of having a full sidebar I only need the feedback button to stick on my lower left side of the screen, when nearing the footer area will stop above it.

[lockedfixed.js](http://www.directlyrics.com/code/lockfixed/demo.html)

Comment: use position fixed on button in css

Comment: @Hushme : I tried adding the position:fixed; but whenever I reached the bottom of the page, it won't stop when it reached the beginning  of footer.

Comment: than use this plugin scrolltofixed search it in google

Comment: @Hushme once again, thank you. I will look into that plugin.

Comment: yes you want to try a plugin for that?

Comment: @Hushme Yes, but the lack of documentation or my lack of understanding has hindered me from implementing it.

I have already put it on my js folder. and made a reference to it by using <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lockfixed.js">

But my problem is how to use it. I know that somewhere i need to use id's that the javascript will recognized.

Comment: no call function on that class

Comment: like $.lockfixed("#sidebar .menu",{offset: {top: 10, bottom: 620}});

Comment: @Hushme well, I tried looking at the source of the demo page, I guess the script was used inside. I'll try to work on that one my code. Thank you for your guidance.

Answer (score 2):

use position fixed in bottom class

```
 .TMDOQ-tab navbar-fixed-bottom
    {
    position: fixed;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`.TMDOQ-tab navbar-fixed-bottom{
position:fixed;bottom:0;left:0
}`